# I messed up the ~/.bashrc file and now terminal doesn't open ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, bash, java, android, jdk

I just installed Android Studio on my ubuntu 16.04 machine and as I didn't want to go to its own home directory and now every single time I try to open the terminal, it tries to start android studio (yes, I'm that noob in ubuntu).

The problem with this is: it can't. Every single time I try to open the terminal, I get this error:

```
No JDK found. Please validate either STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.
```

I have this in `/etc/environment`:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
```

And when I went to android studio's folder and started `studio.sh` (before messing up the `.bashrc` of course) with sudo, it worked.

Anyway, I'm thinking that this happens because .bashrc file is executed without sudo privileges every single time I try to get up a terminal.

What can I do to fix my .bashrc file (at least delete the last 4 lines in it)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click in **Ubuntu** icon (the first bottom in side menu).
2. Write `gedit`
3. Open **Text Editor** clicking in its icon.
4. Click in *Open*.
5. In the list, write: `~/.bashrc`
6. <kbd>Enter</kbd>
7. Clean your failing `.bashrc` file.
8. Save and you can open terminal again.