# Installing python: who is deadsnakes and why should I trust them?

Tags: apt, software-installation, python, security, ppa

I want to install Python 3.9 on my Ubuntu 20.04, and all tutorials I can find include a step as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

I am concerned about security. I've looked into this question: [Are PPAs safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629/538283)

According to the answers, some of the main points to consider are:

- Who made the PPA

  - Someone named deadsnakes, apparently, but what can I conclude from this?
- How many users have used the PPA

  - Where to get this information? [Someone asked this in a comment 9 years ago but it wasn't responded](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for#comment443191_35636).

Attempts to search the internet for *deadsnakes* only brought me into tutorials on how to install Python, which is where I started...

Comment: I've just asked [a question on meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19970/538283) to try to understand why this was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I don't get why this question is receiving so many downvotes.

Comment: Related Q&A: [Are PPAs safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for)

Comment: "who is deadsnakes and why should I trust them?" why would you trust anyone on askubuntu? The one responding mght be deadsnakes :=D

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Because people get emotional when you ask questions about the things they love that they have the answer to, but they themselves don't like the answer to.

Comment: Would the real deadsnakes please stand up?

Comment: @mdhansen hello it me

Comment: (°_°) Did not expect a response from the real maintainer. Color me surprised and happy to see that you're that thorough at looking for comments.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Note: Please don't change the default version of python3. You may end up [destroying Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1397938/124466). Instead, run python3.9 with the command `python3.9`.

Also, you can install python 3.9.5 in Ubuntu 20.04 even without the deadsnake PPA with the commands

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.9
```

For other versions of Ubuntu (e.g. 22.04), you may need the deadsnakes ppa.

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt install python3.9
```

---

Now let's answer your questions.

> Someone named deadsnakes

No, dead*snakes* is a pun on *python*.

> Who made the PPA

As you can see [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), the packages in the PPA are uploaded by [Felix Krull](https://launchpad.net/%7Efkrull) and [Anthony Sottile](https://launchpad.net/%7Easottile).

> How many users have used the PPA

According to [PPA Stats](https://ppa-stats.sheth.io/#/?ppaName=ppa&ppaOwner=deadsnakes&packageName=python3.9), Python3.9 alone has been downloaded 2208666 times, as of writing this answer. On average, there are 10000 downloads per day.

Comment: Note you would have to have the Universe repositories enabled to get python3.9.5

Comment: Is there any reason python3.10 is not in Universe like python3.9? "Unable to locate package python3.10"

Comment: @MikeDalrymple It was released long after 20.04 was released, that's why.

Comment: On 22.04, `universe` is not enough for installing python3.9

Comment: Here is a nice [video](https://youtu.be/Xe40amojaXE) that Anthony talks about it!