# python3.11 package on Ubuntu 22.04 behind

Tags: apt, python, 22.04

I wanted to try Python 3.11 on Ubuntu 22.04, and found the python3.11 family of packages, but it seems to still be on Python 3.11.0rc1. Who maintains it, and will it soon be bumped to the production release?

Edit: deadsnakes looks useful, I'm still curious about the mentioned package(s) though.

Comment: [Python 3.11](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3110/) was released October 24th.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a different Python version using apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-a-different-python-version-using-apt-get)

Comment: ^^^ The above is still true - deadsnakes PPA is still actively maintained.

Comment: @ArturMeinild It's a useful pointer, but doesn't say anything about the python3.11 packages available through the regular apt channels, which I am also curious about (since they appear as the most "official" way to install other python versions).

Comment: I ended up using pyenv instead

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you can find [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/python3.11), the python3.11 package for Jammy is maintained by Ubuntu MOTU developers. You can find their contact information in the same link. The original maintainer in Debian is Matthias Klose.
The website suggests [asking a question](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.11/+addquestion) in Launchpad before contacting the maintainers.

---

Here's how to install latest python 3.11 (not an RC release) on Ubuntu 22.04 (it will be updated later when a new point release of 3.11 is available).

First, add the deadsnakes PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

Then, install python3.11 with

```
sudo apt install python3.11
```

Finally, run it with `python3.11`.

---

**Warning**: Never change the default version of python. You might end up [destroying Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1397938/terminal-not-opening-after-changing-python-version/1397940#1397940).

Comment: Thanks, I'm still curious about the packages I mentioned though. (they also install as python3.11 (not python3).

Comment: @oyvind I have updated the answer