# Problems due to uninstalling system python version. ubuntu-desktop uninstalled

Tags: python, dependencies

I was trying to install lutris and got a mismatched dependencies error. It said my  version of python (3.10) was the problem as it depended on 3.9.

I installed python 3.9 and uninstalled python 3.10 thinking it might work. Now my PC will only boot up in tty.

When I try to reinstall ubuntu-desktop, every single one of the Ubuntu desktop dependencies is mismatched.

Do I try to fix it or just find a pendrive to reinstall the OS?

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop is *dependent* on python3 for many functions, and the default needs to remain the version the tools were coded/tested for, otherwise Ubuntu Desktop will either get removed, or won't reliably work. You can use Ubuntu Server or terminal mode with fewer default python3 (and forget about GUI/desktop) if that helps, but you should not change the *default* version of python3 (*unless happy to live without the features that use it*)    You can re-install Ubuntu Desktop without loosing data or your configs, but your question is without specific Ubuntu product/release details.

Comment: Reinstall Ubuntu. It will be the simplest way to fix the issue. Changing the version of Python will most likely destroy Ubuntu, as many components of the OS heavily depend on it (It is like replacing the vital organs of an organism - unless you really are an expert, it will not go well). However, you can safely install additional versions of Python without replacing the default version. See this answer to know how to install a different version of python without destroying Ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/a/1438713/124466

Comment: I agree it's probably most prudent to reinstall the system and not make the same mistake in the future. However if you really want to try to rescue this installation, please edit your question with specific/exact details. Tell us the commands you are using and provide the output of those commands and all error messages verbatim. Avoid summarizing in your own words because we are unlikely to recognize things that way. Use [code fences](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/20164) when pasting from your terminal.