# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'

Tags: upgrade, python, pip

I update Ubuntu 20.4 to 22.4 and after that **pip** is no longer working in the **virtual environments** based on **python 3.9** and this is the error I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'

What I understood from my searches is that the missing module was in Python3.8 and they suggested to install the module

> sudo apt install python3.8-distutils

I did it and got this error:

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree... Done
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> Package python3.8-distutils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
> This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from Another source
>
> E: Package 'python3.8-distutils' has no installation candidate

I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error when setting up a project that is expecting Python 3.8 on Ubuntu 22.04. Since I had installed Python 3.8 using the [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) already, simply issuing

```
sudo apt install python3.8-distutils
```

solved the problem for me.

Comment: Also for python 3.9 

`sudo apt install python3.9-distutils`

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I decided to try to turn around the problem. I created a backup of my virtual environment then I updated it to python3.10 because with this version pip worked properly.

```
python3.10 -m venv --upgrade my-env
```

this solution apparently works well.

Comment: Never ever install another python version. Python is an integral part of Ubuntu See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1443137/906933) for more infos. Using pipenv or others environments is fine

Comment: You are right and I didn't. As I wrote: "I update Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04" 
I always uses venv and I do every change in the virtual environment that requires changes.
What solved the problem was updating the virtual environment.

Comment: Ah, nice catch. Thanks for sharing.